# Expand date range using JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I have this variable `{{ $daterange }}` with json like this

```
 {
   "starts_at": "2020-05-20",
   "ends_at": "2020-05-23"
 },
 {
   "starts_at": "2020-05-24",
   "ends_at": "2020-05-26"
 },
 {
   "starts_at": "2020-05-27",
   "ends_at": "2020-05-29"
 }
```

What I want to do is to expand something like this,

```
 2020-05-20
 2020-05-21
 2020-05-22
 2020-05-23

 2020-05-24
 2020-05-25
 2020-05-26

 2020-05-27
 2020-05-28
 2020-05-29
```

I'm planning to assign these dates inside of `expandedDate` variable

```
 var expandedDate = [ ....dates ];
```

This should be done using jquery/js

**UPDATE***

Recently this code works and can get all dates between 2 dates. It will list down all dates between 2 date range written in the code.

```
    // Returns an array of dates between the two dates
    var getDates = function(startDate, endDate) {
    var dates = [],
        currentDate = startDate,
        addDays = function(days) {
            var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
            date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
            return date;
        };
    while (currentDate <= endDate) {
        dates.push(currentDate);
        currentDate = addDays.call(currentDate, 1);
    }
    return dates;
    };

    // Usage
    var dates = getDates(new Date(2013,10,22), new Date(2013,11,25));                                                                                                           
    dates.forEach(function(date) {
        console.log(date);
    });
```

How can I populate `{{ $daterange }}` contains multiple date range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think I missed your update with existing code. The following code seems to get the desired output using javascript. Just added comments to each step as an explanation. Hope it is helpful.

```
//sample input data
var daterange = [{
    "starts_at": "2020-05-27",
    "ends_at": "2020-06-23"
  },
  {
    "starts_at": "2020-05-24",
    "ends_at": "2020-05-26"
  },
  {
    "starts_at": "2020-05-27",
    "ends_at": "2020-05-29"
  }
];


// function to get dates between two dates
var getDaysAsArray = function(start_date, end_date) {
  for (var arr = [], d = new Date(start_date); d <= end_date; d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) {
    arr.push(new Date(d));
  }
  return arr;
};

// function to convert date into the format yyyy-mm-dd
var getFormattedDay = function(date) {
  day = date.getDate() < 10 ? "0" + date.getDate() : date.getDate();
  month = date.getMonth()+1 < 10 ? "0" + (date.getMonth()+1) : date.getMonth()+1;
  year = date.getFullYear();
  return year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
}

//main logic
var expandedDate = [];
//Iterate through the list of arrays in the date range
for (var key in daterange) {
  //get first pair of from and to date
  var from_string = daterange[key].starts_at;
  var to_string = daterange[key].ends_at;

  // convert the string date to date format for from and to.
  var from_date = new Date(from_string.replace(/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/, "$1/$2/$3"));
  var to_date = new Date(to_string.replace(/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/, "$1/$2/$3"));

  // call getDaysAsArray to convert dates into strings and into an array.
  var daylist = getDaysAsArray(from_date, to_date);
  // iterate through the daylist and push it into the final array you want to use
  for (var day in daylist) {
    expandedDate.push(getFormattedDay(daylist[day]));

  }

}
// final result required
console.log(expandedDate);
```

Comment: It looks it satisfies the problem, how can I implement here if there's duplicated date will be shown as one. Like if there's `2020-05-1` and another `2020-05-1` it will only show 1 entry as `2020-05-1` not twice?

Comment: There are multiple ways to do that. Simplest way perhaps would be to pass it through a filter. 
```function removeDuplicates(array) {
  return array.filter((a, b) => array.indexOf(a) === b)
};
```
calling  
```removeDuplicates(expandedDate);
```
is one way.

Comment: Thank you for appropriate response, really appreciate the answer little closer to solve the problem. One thing I noticed is that, the current json data on variable is set as month of may, but in the console.log says it is `04` or April.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Rae. The issue was with the getFormattedDay function. getMonth() returns 0 for Jan, 1 for Feb, and so on... so we need to add 1 to the value we get from the method to fix the issue. Just edited the code to reflect the following change:

```month = date.getMonth()+1 < 10 ? "0" + (date.getMonth()+1) : date.getMonth()+1;```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the complete code on how to solve this question

Based on @thommu

```
        var daterange = [
        {
            "starts_at": "2020-05-24",
            "ends_at": "2020-05-26"
        },
        {
            "starts_at": "2020-05-27",
            "ends_at": "2020-05-29"
        }
        ];


    // function to get dates between two dates
    var getDaysAsArray = function(start_date, end_date) {
    for (var arr = [], d = new Date(start_date); d <= end_date; d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) {
        arr.push(new Date(d));
    }
    return arr;
    };

    // function to convert date into the format yyyy-mm-dd
    var getFormattedDay = function(date) {
    day = date.getDate() < 10 ? "0" + date.getDate() : date.getDate();
    month = date.getMonth() < 10 ? "0" + date.getMonth() : date.getMonth();
    year = date.getFullYear();
    return year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
    }

    //main logic
    var expandedDate = [];
    //Iterate through the list of arrays in the date range
    for (var key in daterange) {
    //get first pair of from and to date
    var from_string = daterange[key].starts_at;
    var to_string = daterange[key].ends_at;

    // convert the string date to date format for from and to.
    var xfrom_date = new Date(from_string.replace(/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/, "$1/$2/$3"));
    var xto_date = new Date(to_string.replace(/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/, "$1/$2/$3"));

    //Add +1 month to correct the data
    var from_date = new Date(xfrom_date.setMonth(xfrom_date.getMonth()+1));
    var to_date = new Date(xto_date.setMonth(xto_date.getMonth()+1));

    // call getDaysAsArray to convert dates into strings and into an array.
    var daylist = getDaysAsArray(from_date, to_date);
        // iterate through the daylist and push it into the final array you want to use
        for (var day in daylist) {
            expandedDate.push(getFormattedDay(daylist[day]));

        }
    }
    //Filter Duplicated Dates
    var dateDuplicate = expandedDate;
    var uniqueDate = [];
    $.each(dateDuplicate, function(i, el){
        if($.inArray(el, uniqueDate) === -1) uniqueDate.push(el);
    });

    // final result required
    console.log(uniqueDate);
```